# Modular Database Layout: A correct approach for my use case?

Tags: database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I'm working on a modularized Java Web app. The dependencies between the modules (visible tier) and the business/database tier is resolved by gradle. So technically, my database only needs to hold tables for the entities, that are actually used by the deployed visible modules. But this may lead to potential trouble when I want to migrate the database in the production environment. So, other than creating the database schema from the dependencies, I see two options:

1) I always have a single schema for all available entities. My actual database therefore holds the tables for all entities, even the ones not used by any of the deployed modules. This makes migration in a production environment very easy, but clutters up the database and the folders that hold the entities during development.

2) I have several independent schemas, which are logically separated. Each schema will result in a database on the server. Which schemas are needed, is resolved by the module dependencies. I migrate every schema for itself. So migration will still be manageable.

The server for the databases would look like this:

- MySqlServer

  - AuthorizationDatabase

    - UserTable
    - RoleTable
    - UserRoleRelationshipTable
  - BlogPostDatabase

    - PostTable
    - CommentsTable

etc..

However, I don't know if the idea of many smaller databases instead of one monolithic database will lead to potential trouble. Especially in regards of performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a single database for the following reasons:

a) MySQL can handle a few thousand tables depending on the available server resources

b) It is easier to manage

c) If the customer base grows outside the limits of one server, you can create a new server to handle a new batch of customers and then scale that too